# Do I have to go through customs and immigrations for my Dublin, Ireland layover?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, ireland, common-travel-area

I am flying from NYC to Edinburgh, Scotland with a layover in Dublin, Ireland. Will I have to go through customs and immigration in Dublin or just immigration?

Comment: Are your two flights on the same ticket, or booked separately?

Comment: My tickets are booked together!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ll go through immigration in Dublin, then your flight to Edinburgh will be treated almost like a domestic flight, and you won’t go through immigration again in Edinburgh, although you will go through UK customs.

In general, the rules of the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area) mean that when admitted to one country you can travel to the other fairly freely.

There are a few complications though:

- The length of time you can stay in the UK may differ from what you'd get if you enter the UK directly.
- If you require visas to enter the UK and/or Ireland, you will need to get both, even though it’s unlikely you’ll ever meet UK border agents. If you're travelling with an American passport this won't be an issue for you.

The UK government website has more information about [travelling from Ireland to the UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/travelling-between-the-uk-and-ireland-isle-of-man-guernsey-or-jersey#travelling-from-ireland-to-the-uk)